# Name of files in a specific directory using matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to find the name of files in a specific directory. I know that the dir command return the name of files but it contains the file name with the their extension. Therefore, I used strfind to remove the extension of files as follows:

```
a = dir(fullfile(dataset_path, [dataset_category '\qrel']))
for i= 3: length(a)
  name{i} =  a(i).name(1:strfind(a(i).name, '.')-1)
```

I want a better approach without loop. I wonder is it a way to use vectorization for this purpose. I used the following code but it return an error

```
a = dir(fullfile(dataset_path, [dataset_category '\qrel']))
name = a.name(1:strfind(a.name, '.')-1)
```

Comment: what's wrong with the loop approach?

Comment: I need to process text data. I wonder is it possible to process cell arrays faster using vectorization approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with regular expressions:

```
name = regexprep({a.name}, '\.[^\.]*$', '');
```

This collects all names in a cell array (`{a.name}`). For each string it matches a dot (`\.`) followed by zero or more characters other than a dot (`[^\.]*`) at the end of the string (`$`), and removes that. Thanks to @Shai for the "other than a dot" correction, which makes sure that only the final dot is matched.

Comment: what if there are several dots in the name? shouldn't `'\.[^.]*$'` be a better expression?

Comment: Well spotted! Thank you very much. Corrected